# How to group an array of objects based on a dot-separated string of numbers

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as the following

```
const sample = [
    { id: '1' },
    { id: '1.1' },
    { id: '1.1.1' },
    { id: '1.1.2' },
    { id: '1.2' },
    { id: '1.2.1' },
    { id: '1.2.1.1' },
    { id: '2' },
    { id: '2.1' }
];
```

I'd like to create a new array to include the children under their parent based on `id` property as the following

```
[
    {
        id: '1',
        children: [
            {
                id: '1.1',
                children: [
                    { id: '1.1.1' },
                    { id: '1.1.2' }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: '1.2',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: '1.2.1',
                        children: [{ id: '1.2.1.1' }]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        children: [ { id: '2.1' } ]
    }
]
```

I'm not sure how to do it or from where to start

Comment: I'd probably start with looking into regex mixed with some array operations like Array.prototype.map(), etc.

Comment: Is your test case wrong? I see 1.3 in the input, and 1.2 in the output

Comment: Is it possible to have an invalid id (something that’s not “dot-separated numbers”)? What about duplicate ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map to keep track of parents and children, then get the entries that are the roots as your result:

```js
const data = [
    { id: '1' },
    { id: '1.1' },
    { id: '1.1.1' },
    { id: '1.1.2' },
    { id: '1.3' },
    { id: '1.3.1' },
    { id: '1.3.1.1' },
    { id: '2' },
    { id: '2.1' }
];

const map = new Map();

data.forEach(({ id }) => {
    // exclude last bit to get parent id
    const parent = id.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
    
    // our entry - needs to be like this since
    // we want a reference to the same object
    const entry = { id, children: [] };
    
    // won't run if this is a root
    if (parent)
        // add child to parent
        map.get(parent).children.push(entry);
    
    // add to map
    map.set(id, entry);
});

const result = Array.from(map)
    // get roots - keys that only have one part
    .filter(([key]) => key.split(".").length === 1)
    // map to entry values
    .map(([, value]) => value);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: This code only works if the array comes appropriately sorted as in the example. Otherwise it will throw.

Comment: @user776686 Shouldn't be too hard to sort it then :) If you do find a way to do it without needing the input to be sorted beforehand, you are always free to post an answer.